# Codeigniter does not load Upload Library

Tags: php, codeigniter

We are trying to upload some files with Codeigniter, and for some reason this piece of code is not working.

Loading the library in "autoload" works perfectly, still, not the best solution, for the obvious reasons.

Curiously, is working in another website that I have.

```
<?php
// set options
$config['upload_path']      = FCPATH.$path;
$config['allowed_types']    = 'png|jpeg|jpg|gif';
$config['max_size']         = 2048;
$config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;
$config['overwrite']        = TRUE;
$config['max_width']        = 0;
$config['max_height']       = 0;
// check if folder exists
if( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']))
  @mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0755, true);
//load upload library
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
//check success of upload
if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name)) 
  return $this->upload->display_errors();
else
{
  // do upload
}
?>
```

Here is the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: xxx::$upload

Filename: core/xxx.php

Line Number: 424

Fatal error: Call to a member function do_upload() on null
```

Comment: Just for sake of curiosity try with `$this->load->library('upload'); $this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: Codeigniter does not load Upload Library?? Does it mean codeigniter doing something wrong? or you cannot figure out what mistake you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure `$path` is correct var dump($path) and check receiving it.

Second you did not have any `{}` in if part of do_upload and around the is directory

```
public function do_upload() {

$config['upload_path']      = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']    = 'png|jpeg|jpg';
$config['max_size']         = 2048;
$config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;
$config['max_size'] = '30000'; // Added Max Size
$config['overwrite']        = TRUE;
$config['max_width']        = 0;
$config['max_height']       = 0;

//load upload library

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

// check if folder exists

if( ! is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
@mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0755, true);
}

//check success of upload

$name = "userfile"; // Field name

if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name)) {

  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

  $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);

} else {

  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

  $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);

}

}
```

Make sure on view use `echo form_open_multipart('controller/do_upload')`

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html